# Get the size in 'px' instead of percents

Tags: javascript, css

I have to write a javascript function that is returning the current size (in `px`) of a div. Unfortunately the div has its weight specified in `%` instead of `px`.

The style of the div: `position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;`

And my width returning function:

```
function getTableWidth(tableId){
    var tabWidth = document.getElementById('pt1::tabb').children[0].children[0].style.width;
    return tabWidth;
}
```

`tabWidth` is '100%'.

Is it possible to return the `px` width instead of the `%` width ?

**NOTE**: I don't have access to any html/css , as the page I am working on is generated through a complex framework. I can only embed javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each browser is different. In most you can use the `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` properties of the DOM element. In non-IE browsers you can use `document.defaultView.getComputedStyle()`. However I'd recommend using a framework that takes care of cross-browser issues for you. In jQuery, you can get the current width in pixels using something as simple as `$(element).width()`.

Comment: +1 for giving the ways other than jQuery (a good answer it it's own right) as the OP may not be able/willing to add jQuery to their complex framework output.

Comment: Thank you, it works. The problem is we are using Oracle ADF 11g, and I cannot use JQuery. I only need some small javascript code in order to customize some 'uncustomizable' components.

Comment: Or if use Prototype (new as of 1.7RC1): `$(tableId).getLayout().get('width')`: http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element/layout/

Answer (score 2):

```
node.offsetWidth
```

should do the trick (in all browsers!)